# How to use/integrate/connect firebase authentication to existing express app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

Goal: I have existing express app (On AWS EC2 with MySql) with JWT authentication using simple email & pwd. All this API are authenticated with JWT token.

Now I want my client (Android/iOS/Web) to use firebase SDK to use its authentication service to get access to my express APIs.

So basically I want to use firebase authentication to give access to my server APIs. In addition I also want to exchange user data between my express mySql server and firebase database users

Any resources/suggestion will be helpful

**UPDATE**:

I would also like to know if any cost involved in this type of integration as firebase says all social authentication is free but here we might be calling firebase service for each API request to authenticate user so not sure if there is any hidden cost for that

Thanks in advance